# Having both mousedown/mouseup and dblclick in jQuery

Tags: jquery, events

Whenever a mousedown or mouseup handler is attached to an element the dblclick cannot be attached (won't work if attached), though this seems fair enough is there any way to reinstate a dblclick functionality without rewriting it from scratch (sigh...)
Or am I missing something about events propagation?

Comment: Can't reproduce this in any browser. Suspect something else is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

It works - place this code in Firebug on this very page and you'll see it working (try double clicking on the text of your question):

```
($('.post-text')
    .mousedown(function () { console.log('down'); })
    .mouseup(function () { console.log('up'); })
    .dblclick(function () { console.log('dbclick'); }));
```

---

*Don't have [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)? Go grab it, I'll wait!*

Comment: Thanks Emil,
I was in Opera 10.10, a similar (homemade) debugging code works but hapazardly:
 scrollframe
 .mousedown(function (evt) { eventlog(evt, ' ', false); })
 .mouseup(function (evt) { eventlog(evt, ' ', false); })
 .dblclick(unscroll);

It seems there are doubleclick problems with Opera, plus the context is a bit more complicated the non responsive div area is scrollable and also contains draggable objects.
Anyway that was a stupid question, since I need to defer the action on the mousedown I will test for a still running timeout on the second mousedown.
(comment limit sucks)

Answer (score 3):

The event.detail parameter will count how many consecutive clicks you had so its possible to use that to detect that a double click has happened.

```
$('#mybutton').on('click',function(e) {
  console.log("User left clicked!"); // do select code
  if (e.button == 0 && e.detail == 2) {
    console.log("User left doubleclicked!"); // do action code
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Though this question is really old I want to show how I managed with this.

This block **won't** work:

```
        $(element).on('mousedown', function(event) {
            ...
        });

        $(element).on('dblclick', function(event) {
            ...
        });
```

But you can use this snippet to create the same behavior handler:

```
        var clicks = 0, delay = 400;
        $(element).on('mousedown', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            clicks++;

            setTimeout(function() {
                clicks = 0;
            }, delay);

            if (clicks === 2) {
                // double click event handler should be here
                clicks = 0;
                return;
            } else {
                // mousedown event handler should be here
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks. It is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Your mousedown and mouseup cannot:

1. do e.stopPropagate etc.
2. return false

and it should work if Your code doesn't have a conflict between them methods